execute "code --uninstall-extension [extension-id]" command failed in vscode extension host
Using node "execSync" func execute "code --uninstall-extension [extension-id]" command in extension host, but got "code: bad option: --uninstall-extension" result, meanwhile executes successfully in vscode terminal or os terminal.
Is there any policy limit to the uninstall command in vscode?
I have tried to use "spawnSync" to replace "execSync", or use "work_threads" to start a child thread to execute the command, but they all failed.
